# Is it possible to convert NetMTLMv2 hash to NTLM hash?

Tags: hash, type-conversion, ntlm

Is there any way to convert NetNTLMv2 to ntlm hashes?
For instance ntlm value of the 123 is

```
3DBDE697D71690A769204BEB12283678
```

Same password for user "try" in computer "PC" which has private ip address 192.168.73.130 NetNTLMv2 value is

```
try::PC:d158262017948de9:91642a8388d64d40f6c31b694e79363e: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
```

Can we convert this NetNTLMv2 to NTLM (`3DBDE697D71690A769204BEB12283678`) without knowing any credentials?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no answer :) But it is ok, because I did a little research and found the answer. For now, there is no way to convert NetNTLMv2 to NTLM. Actually NTLM hash is the first key to generate NetNTLMv2. I decided to explain how it works.

[image: Simple Mechanism of NetNTLMv2 Response]

To calculate and compare NTLMv2 you should first calculate the NTLM value of the password which is **`123`** in this case.  To demonstrate it, I'll use **python 2.7**. Before starting you should import those modules **`hashlib, binascii, hmac`** .

NTLM value of **`123`** calculated with python like this:

```
_ntlm = hashlib.new("md4", "123".encode("utf-16-le")).digest()
ntlm = binascii.hexlify(_ntlm)
```

The result is **`3dbde697d71690a769204beb12283678`** and this value will be used as key for the first HMAC_MD5 calculation.

To do that we should concatenate the user name and domain name. If you don't work on the domain, you'll use your computer name. In this case, my username is **`try`** and my computer name is **`PC`**.
When we concatenate it, it'll become **`tryPC`**. Then this value is converted into unicode uppercase in little-endian format. We'll generate HMAC_MD5 hash of this value with using NTLM of **`123`** as a key.

```
"tryPC"==> "TRYPC" ==> '54005200590050004300' (UTF-16-le in hexadecimal)
```

We calculate this in Python like:

```
"tryPC".upper().encode("utf-16-le").encode("hex")
```

Then we calculate **HMAC_MD5(54005200590050004300)** with key **3dbde697d71690a769204beb12283678**

In python it is calculated like this:

```
firstHMAC = hmac.new("3dbde697d71690a769204beb12283678".decode("hex"),"54005200590050004300".decode("hex"),hashlib.md5).hexdigest()
firstHMAC ==> 2381ca3f5e9c4534722cd511f6a4c983
```

After that we'll use **firstHMAC as a key** to calculate the HMAC_MD5 value of the **Type2 challenge**.

Type2 challenge is combined with server challenge and blob.

Network response for NetNTLMv2 is like this:

```
try::PC:d158262017948de9:91642a8388d64d40f6c31b694e79363e: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
```

When we split this response according to **`:`** index 3 is the server challenge which is **`d158262017948de9`**
Index 5 which starts like **`"01010000..."`** indicates the blob value. Blob value also consists of blob signature, reserved fields, timestamp, random client nonce and target information. I don't give detail about the blob.

To calculate NTLMv2 we should concatenate the server challenge and the blob to calculate the HMAC_MD5 value of this by using **`firstHMAC`** as a key.

In Python we do that like this:

```
firstHMAC = "2381ca3f5e9c4534722cd511f6a4c983"
type2Challange = "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"
ntlmv2 = hmac.new(firstHMAC.decode("hex"),type2Challange.decode("hex"),hashlib.md5).hexdigest()
ntlmv2 ==> 91642a8388d64d40f6c31b694e79363e
```

If this value is equal to the 4th index of the NetNTLMv2 response, you'll be verified. In this case, the 4th index is equal to **`91642a8388d64d40f6c31b694e79363e`** and that means you have the correct password.

According to server challenge and blob value, you'll always get the different NTLMv2 value and you only can calculate this if you have the correct password.

In other words, we can produce NetNTLMv2 with NTLM. However, we cannot convert back NetNTLMv2 to NTLM because [cryptographic] hash functions are one-way functions.